# function st_length3d(geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, st-geometry

Whenever I execute this query:

```
SELECT ST_Length3D(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0,5 0 3,5 10 5)'));
```

Postgresql is throwing an error:

> ERROR: function st_length3d(geometry) does not exist SQL state: 42883

but this query running fine and showing result:

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0,5 0 3,5 10 5)'));
```

It seems that ST_Length3D is not added in my system defined function any idea how to recover this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostGIS 2.x, the function `ST_Length3d` has been renamed `ST_3dLength`: [ST_3DLength](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_3DLength.html). This query will work:

```
# SELECT ST_3dLength(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0 0,5 0 3,5 10 5)'));
   st_3dlength    
------------------
 16.0289909220309
(1 row)
```